Tried to queue enemy attacks but they attack too fast and simultaneously
I'm newbie with programming and Unity. I was trying to make a queue for the second enemy to attack only when the first finishes its attack, but it just doesn't work: they attack much much faster and simultaneously, and I can't figure out why. The player practically gets insta-killed.
This is the code from the AI script where the Attack is located:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyIA : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Attack and RandomPos
    public Animator anim;
    public Transform player;
    public GameObject alertPrefab;
    public float damage = 10;
    public float attackDelay = 1.3f;
    public float alertDelay = 0.5f;
    public PlayerController playerController;
    public PlayerHealthManager playerHealthManager;

    //Health Management
    public float health;
    public float maxHealth = 100;
    public float defense;
    HealthBar healthBar;
    EnemyController enemyController;
    public Transform controller;
    public bool isAlive { get; private set; } = true;

    public static List<Vector3> attackPositions = new List<Vector3>()
    {
        new Vector3(-7.5f, 1, 0),
        new Vector3(-5, 1, 0),
        new Vector3(-7.5f, -1, 0),
        new Vector3(-5, -1, 0),
        new Vector3(-7.5f, -3, 0),
        new Vector3(-5f, -3, 0)
    };

    void Awake()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        playerHealthManager = player.GetOrAddComponent<PlayerHealthManager>();
        playerController = player.GetOrAddComponent<PlayerController>();
        healthBar = GetComponentInChildren<HealthBar>();
        enemyController = controller.GetOrAddComponent<EnemyController>();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        health = maxHealth;
    }
    
    public IEnumerator Attack()
    {

        while(true)
        {
            List<int> attackingPositions = TakeRandomPositions();
            
            List<GameObject> actualAlerts = new List<GameObject>();
            foreach(int posicao in attackingPositions)
            {
                Vector3 targetPosition = attackPositions[posicao];
                GameObject alert = Instantiate(alertPrefab, targetPosition, Quaternion.identity);
                actualAlerts.Add(alert);
            }

            anim.SetBool("Attack", true);
            
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(alertDelay);

            foreach(GameObject alert in actualAlerts)
            {
                Destroy(alert);
            }

            if(attackingPositions.Contains(playerController.currentIndex))
            {
                playerHealthManager.TakeDamage(damage);
            }

            anim.SetBool("Attack", false);
            Debug.Log("Inimigo " + gameObject.name + " terminou de atacar!");
        } 
    }

    private List<int> TakeRandomPositions()
    {
        List<int> attackingSelectedPositions = new List<int>{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        int firstPosition = attackingSelectedPositions[Random.Range(0, attackingSelectedPositions.Count)];
        attackingSelectedPositions.Remove(firstPosition);
        int secondPosition = attackingSelectedPositions[Random.Range(0, attackingSelectedPositions.Count)];
        attackingSelectedPositions.Remove(secondPosition);
        int thirdPosition = attackingSelectedPositions[Random.Range(0, attackingSelectedPositions.Count)];

        return new List<int>{firstPosition, secondPosition, thirdPosition};
    }

    public void TakeDamage(float damage)
    {
        float damageReduced = damage * (1- (defense / 100f));

        health -= damageReduced;
        healthBar.UpdateHealthBar(health, maxHealth);
        Debug.Log("Esqueleto recebeu " + damageReduced + " de dano!");

        if(health <= 0)
        {
            isAlive = false;
            Debug.Log(gameObject.name + " morreu");
            enemyController.EnemyDeafeted(gameObject);

        }
    }

    public void Die()
    {
        anim.SetBool("Morte", true);
    }

}

And this is the code of the Controller which starts the Attack Couroutine, destroys the enemies, moves them, etc.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static Vector3[] enemyPositions =
    {
        new Vector3(-0.7f, -0.3f, 0),
        new Vector3(0.9f, -0.9f, 0),
        new Vector3(2.5f, -1, 0),
    };
    
    public List<GameObject> enemies;
    public List<EnemyIA> enemyIA;
    public Queue<EnemyIA> attackQueue = new Queue<EnemyIA>();

    EnemyIA enemyIa;
    public Transform ia;
    private bool isAttacking = false;

    void Awake()
    {
        enemyIa = ia.GetComponent<EnemyIA>();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < enemies.Count && i < enemyPositions.Length; i++)
        {
            enemies[i].transform.position = enemyPositions[i];

        }

        foreach(EnemyIA enemy in enemyIA)
        {
            attackQueue.Enqueue(enemy);
            Debug.Log("Estou sendo enfilheirado" + enemy.name);
        }
        
        if(attackQueue.Count > 0)
        {
            StartCoroutine(AttackQueue());
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator AttackQueue()
    {
        while(true)
        {   
            if(attackQueue.Count > 0 && !isAttacking)
            {
                isAttacking = true;

                EnemyIA currentEnemy = attackQueue.Dequeue();

                Debug.Log("Deu Deqeue");

                if(currentEnemy != null)
                {
                    StartCoroutine(currentEnemy.Attack());

                    Debug.Log(currentEnemy.name +" atacou");
                }

                yield return new WaitForSeconds(enemyIa.attackDelay);

                if(currentEnemy != null && currentEnemy.isAlive)
                {
                    attackQueue.Enqueue(currentEnemy);
                    Debug.Log("Deu Queue");
                }

                isAttacking = false;
            }

            yield return null;
        }

    }

    public void EnemyDeafeted(GameObject deadEnemy)
    {
        int index = enemies.IndexOf(deadEnemy);
        if (index == -1) return;
       
        enemies.RemoveAt(index);
        var scriptEnemy = deadEnemy.GetComponent<EnemyIA>();
        if(scriptEnemy != null)
        {
            scriptEnemy.Die();
        }

        for(int i = index; i < enemies.Count; i++)
        {
            enemies[i].transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(enemies[i].transform.position, enemyPositions[i], 0.5f);
        }
    }
}


When do you stop an enemy's attack? It looks like every time it's that enemy's turn, you start a new Attack coroutine, even though the earlier ones are still running infinitely because of the while (true)
